# is { {a} , {∅, {a} } } a legitimate set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is $\{\varnothing,a\} = \{a\}$?

Hence is $\{ \{a\} , \{\varnothing, \{a\} \} \}$ a legitimate set?

Are they the same?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Note that $\{x,x\}$ is absolutely legitimate to write down, but it just means the same as $\{x\}$ because doubled elements are ignored.

Comment: @M.Winter: why this remark ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I see no other reason why OP should be concerned that his set is not legitimate. Assuming $\{a,\varnothing\}=a$ the second set will be $\{\{a\},\{a\}\}$. OP seems to be concerned that no element can appear twice in the set builder notation.

Comment: @M.Winter: no, the set will be $\{\{a\},a\}$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust He used $\{\varnothing,a\}$ in the first line, but $\{\varnothing,\{a\}\}$ in the second!

Comment: @M.Winter: so the second set is even less of the form $\{\{a\},\{a\}\}$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust It is not, but it would be under this false assumption from line 1.

Comment: @M.Winter: I don't see that. Can you elaborate ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust If OP thinks $\{\varnothing,\color{red}{a}\}=\color{red}{a}$, then I thought that he also might think that $\{\varnothing,\color{red}{\{a\}}\}=\color{red}{\{a\}}$. This would imply that the second set reduces to $\{\{a\},\{a\}\}$. So I interpreted his concerns about the legitimacy as explained in my first comment. I might be wrong, though.

Comment: @M.Winter Unfortunately $\{\emptyset, a\} = a$ is something that happened by your editing. Earlier it was $\{\emptyset, a\} = \{a\}$. Please be careful when editing other peoples question so that you don't change the meaning of them (and then blaming them for your formulation).

Comment: @skyking I am so sorry. I edited it again and now its clear why my comment was not useful.

Answer (score 3):

Question 1 : As $\varnothing$ is an element of your set, the two sets aren't equal. Left : 2 elements, right : 1 element.

As long as $a$ exists, the 2 sets are different.

Question 2 :

Yes, it is a legitimate set.

Comment: Yes : the global sets contains 2 elements : $\{ a \}$ and $\{ \varnothing, \{ a \} \}$.

Comment: Who says $a$ only has one element? Even if $a=\emptyset$ you have two different sets.

Comment: @skyking I never said $a$ contains one element but $a$ is an element of the global set. For the second point, you are correct : I edited accordingly.

Comment: The question now says $\{\emptyset, \{a\}\}$ and $a$. The argument that the former has two and the later one element means that $a$ would contain precisely one element.

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not equal, in general. While $\varnothing = \{\}$ has no elements, it is a set. In other words, $\varnothing \in \{\varnothing, a\}$ but $\varnothing \notin\{a\}$, which means the two sets are different.

Yes, $\{\{a\},\{\varnothing, a\}\}$ is a legitimate set, and it is different from $\{\{a\}\}$, unless $a = \varnothing$.

Answer (score 1):

The second is legitimate set, assuming that $a$ itself is legitimate.

The first is not true (as it currently stands). A set can't be a member of itself. That is we always have $a\notin a$, but we have $a\in \{\emptyset, a\}$. Therefore $\{\emptyset, a\}\ne a$.

Before edited it said if $\{\emptyset, a\} = \{a\}$ which can be true. If $a=\emptyset$ then it's true, but otherwise it isn't since then $\emptyset$ is not a member of the RHS, but a member to the LHS.